# Docker build fails to run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been trying to build some docker containers for a project I'm working on and 2/3 days ago the process would run smoothly.. somehow yesterday and today there seems to be an issue with running the build and it makes no sense because I haven't changed anything and I'm suspecting its an issue with Docker itself.  (Im on a mac if that makes any difference) The error is below

```
[internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.6.5:

failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.6.5": dialing registry-1.docker.io:443 with direct connection: resolving host registry-1.docker.io: lookup registry-1.docker.io: no such host
```

Comment: Any idea how to fix that? i even uninstalled and reinstalled it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are having DNS names resolution trouble.

> lookup registry-1.docker.io: no such host

That message actually means that the docker daemon has tried to pull an image from the public registry: **registry-1.docker.io**, but failed because the DNS name of the host was not resolved.

Try to resolve the IP address of this DNS name yourself via `nslookup` or `dig` utilities, like:

```
nslookup registry-1.docker.io
```

If it outputs something like:

> ** server can't find registry-1.docker.io: NXDOMAIN

then you have a problem - the DNS server, that your laptop is connected to, cannot resolve this domain name, or there is a misconfiguration on your local host.

It might also be because you are inside the corporate network, e.g. you have connected via VPN to it. Then it could be because the DNS server in this network is unable to resolve this host.

As a **temporary solution**, you can try to edit your **resolv.conf** generated file. I do not know for sure, but I guess it should be at this location (as most Linux distributions have): **/etc/resolv.conf**

You can try to set **the first line** to the following

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
# all other stuff here
```

This is a google DNS server AFAIK. If there is a local misconfiguration on your laptop you will be able to at least get by with this.

P.S: This file is generated at boot each time (not the only way to regenerate it but still), so your changes will not be persistent.